# iOS7 view with autolayout to line up above TabBar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, autolayout, ios7

I know I know.. Another iOS7 question.
I have a view in a UINavigationController which gets added to a TabBarController.
In iOS6 I used the vertical constraint 'bottom space to super view, default' which would give me 10 pixels about the TabBar.
This same constraint doesn't appear to work in iOS 7. Is the TabBar not considered the superview anymore? Is there another constraint I should be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every view controller now is full screen, so your view starts on 0,0 (under the status bar) and ends under the tab bar.

With auto layout you can use a new property in UIViewController called bottomLayoutGuide. As the [iOS 7 UI Transitioning Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1) says:

> The topLayoutGuide and bottomLayoutGuide properties indicate the location of the top or bottom bar edges in a view controller’s view. If bars should overlap the top or bottom of a view, you can use Interface Builder to position the view relative to the bar by creating constraints to the bottom of topLayoutGuide or to the top of bottomLayoutGuide. (If no bars should overlap the view, the bottom of topLayoutGuide is the same as the top of the view and the top of bottomLayoutGuide is the same as the bottom of the view.) Both properties are lazily created when requested.

Comment: There is currently a bug with iOS7, where the bottom layout guide height is not set correctly when switching tabs in the tab bar.

Comment: The `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` properties are only accessible from Interface Builder when using Storyboards and not with standard NIBs it would seem...

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Auto Layout. Please unchecked "Extend Edges>Under Bottom Bars" setting checked for your tabbarcontroller in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 7:

In the views hierarchies of tabbar, **topView->parentView-> .... ->rootView**

Do the following for eachView from top till root:: Add constraints **left, top, right, bottom** to each of the view.